# Can not start node app unless changing directory

Tags: node.js, command-line, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, cd

I am trying to create a cron job which starts my node app every hour, the command that starts is:

```
node /home/pi/Desktop/DiscordBots/panda-bot/index.js
```

however this returns:

```
fs.js:646
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'warnings.json'
```

It does start if I cd to the directory first `/home/pi/Desktop/DiscordBots/panda-bot` and then `node index.js`

This would mean I have to create a shell script that cds and then starts node but I prefer to do start it in one line, is this possible?

Comment: you could make your cron job run `cd <path> && node <path>/index.js`

Comment: Didnt  know I could use logical operators, thanks!

Comment: You could also make your script not depend upon the current directory at ll.  You would have to show us the portion of code causing the error for us to advise on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron runs your commands in your home directory.
If you want a oneliner command in your crontab then you would have to use &&

In your crontab

`0 * * * * cd /home/pi/Desktop/DiscordBots/panda-bot && node index.js`

Please refer to :https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/what-is-the-working-directory-when-cron-executes-a-job